# Set text of textbox bold and blue

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to set the text of textbox (or label) to bold and change its color to blue in the same line.

At the moment I am using this.

```
label1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
label1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Is there a one liner code to do that. 
Thanks !

Comment: What benefit do you think you'll get from doing this in a single line?

Comment: just put them in one line... :P

Comment: Remove the `\n\r` after `label1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
label1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold); label1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

That's all you can do.

In other words, no. The font and the color it is rendered in are completely independent, which is why there are no color-related properties in the `Font` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is to create an extension method. Under the hood it would still be multi-line, but if you want the code to be a one-liner where you are actually making the change, that syntactic sugar should suffice. Something like,

```
public static class LabelHelper
{
    public static Label ChangeFormatting(this Label label, Font font, Color color, Color color)
    {
        if (label == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        label.Font = font;
        label.ForeColor = color;
    }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
label1.ChangeFormatting(new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Color.Blue);
```